# Visual Studio 2008 File has a different computed hash than specified in manifest on Application installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

When I run the app on debug mode it works without any error. Also it works when I run the exe file from Debug folder. However when I build or publish the application it provides file has a different computed hash.  The error details:

```
APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\Windows7\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM\TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM\bin\Release\TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + File, TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:32 PM] : Activation of C:\Users\Windows7\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM\TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM\bin\Release\TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM.application has started.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:32 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:32 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:32 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 2.0.50727.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil using Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil using WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [25-Feb-16 1:19:34 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (HashValidation)
        - File, TELEPHONE ORDERING SYSTEM.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, Hash hash)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, HashCollection hashCollection)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: The file was changed when it traveled from your machine to the user's machine.  Comparing the hash protects against a man-in-the-middle attack.  Why it changed is of course never obvious from such an error message.  Ask the user to send a copy back and you can find out more.  Be careful with it, you can't trust it.

Comment: No i get the error in same machine that i use to build the code. There is no change of device at this stage.

Comment: Then maybe you shouldn't trust that machine :-P.  Try another one.

Comment: I did try in different machine too same problem